# valueerror setting an array element with a sequence sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, logistic-regression

I have a problem with numpy arrays, I have a big data set of entries, and all the entries have float values and each entry is of same size (300), when passing it as input to logistic regression model, it throws up an error saying i have replaced an array element with a sequence.

i have checked if each datatype is array or not, they are arrays of datatype float

```
print(type(train_on[0][0]))
print(type(train_on[0]))
print(type(train_on))
```

gives an output of

```
<class 'numpy.float32'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I read on other related posts that this error occurs mostly because of irregular sizes of entries, but my dataset has a length of 300 for each instance. Just to make sure each of them has same length, I cross checked with help of the following code, and every entry has same size

```
count=0
for i in range(train_on.shape[0]):
    if train_on[i].size==300:
        count+=1
print(count)
count/train.shape[0]
```

and it returns

```
66376
1.0
```

the error is popping up when I am trying to pass it up into a logistic regression model

```
    logr = LogisticRegression(solver='sag')
    logr.fit(train_on,train['A'])
```

this is the error

```
--> 522                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    523             except ComplexWarning:
    524                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

can anyone help me with this

Comment: can you explain train['A'], what's the shape of train_on and of train['A'] exactly? and try using a numpy array there: train['A'].values

Comment: I figured the problem out. The model was expecting an array of lists. where as I have passed array of arrays